# how to invoke function prop in a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

how to invoke AddToCart prop in TopComponent?
here is what i tried but this doesn't work

```
type MainState = {
AddToCart: (e) => void;
};

export class MainComponent extends React.Component<{}, MainState> {

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <TopComponent AddToCart={this.state.AddToCart}></TopComponent>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              AddToCart(e) {
                return "someValue"
              },
            })
          }}
        ></button>
      </>
    );
  }

}
```

props in TopComponent

```
type TopProps = {
  AddToCart?: (e) => void;
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing a function in state?

Comment: This is what i came to. any suggestions?

Comment: React doesn't support functions in state. Can read about props vs state here: https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md

Comment: Interesting didn't know that before. so how i can invoke the function property in TopComponent?

Comment: You pass the function as a prop, then you can call it via `props.AddToCart()`.

Comment: Now im getting this.props.AddToCart is not a function, what im trying to do is re render CartPopupComponent which is inside the TopComponent. should i use redux for this?

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. `CartPopupComponent` is not mentioned in your original question, or what you want to with it.

Comment: Right now all i want is to pass data to TopComponent upon clicking. i thought the answer gonna be simple it turns out communicating between react components are not that simple. i found this article to be helpful https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/react-communicating-between-components